# CORS in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and I need to make a cross-domain POST request to another domain. Code runs in Chrome `Content Script` environment which has some limitations.

I inject my code in a specific site with domain looks like `service.site.com` and I have to make a request to the domain like `api.site.com`

The response headers from `api.site.com` looks like

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Accept
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: https://service.site.com
```

As you see that another domain allows requests from `service.site.com`. It means an *Origin* header of my request headers should contain that Origin.

But chrome extension adds an Origin header for me!

Now it sends a request to `api.site.com` with a header

```
Origin: chrome-extension://oeminagccdkclchnelmkbkcpcfnjgofj
```

and `api.site.com` may block it? I do not receive anything in a response. A request crashes and I see no error and no data in response.

Of course I added permissions in manifest file:

```
"permissions": [
  "*://service.site.com/*",
  "*://api.site.com/*"
],
```

And it still doesn't work. Chrome extension continues change Origin header and server doesn't respond. OR does it respond but my browser blocks it? I can't find out. If I run that request in WEB-script environment, it works well and I see a response from server. But I still have to run it in a Content-script environment.

I even tried to inject a function with post request in a web-script environment and call it from content-script environment but if I do it such way, it adds that Origin header and it doesn't work.

I also tried to change Response headers using Chrome extension features hoping that would help

```
const responseListener = function(details){
  const out = [];
  details.responseHeaders.forEach(item => {
    if (item.name.toLowerCase() !== 'access-control-allow-origin') {
      out.push(item);
    }
  });
  out.push({name: 'access-control-allow-origin', value: '*'});
  return {responseHeaders: out};
};

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(responseListener, {urls: ["*://*/*"]},
  ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

Now it shows that `api.site.com` returns my header but it still doesn't help.

Comment: Make the request in your background script and send the results back via messaging as shown in the [official explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) (section 2).